# Spring Kafka doesn't returns null for Tombstone records during batch processing

Tags: spring-kafka

Seems that spring Spring Kafka ignores `@Payload(required = false)` annotation during Batch processing. At-least, instead of getting `null` for  `Tombstone` I always receives `KafkaNull` objects regardless what set in `@Payload` annotation.

My code looks is as follows:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = ["\${kafka.topic.categories}"])
fun receive(
   @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) List<String> keys,
   @Payload(required = false) categories: List<Category>
) {
    ...
}
```

Nothing special. I receives a list of entries, but always `KafkaNull` as `Tombstone` record, which leads to a class-cast exception.

In non-batch mode everything works perfectly as expected.

Do you have any idea why is that?

**UPDATE:**
It was fixed via https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/974

Answer (score 0):

It's a limitation of the way argument conversion is achieved.

With a `List<Foo>` the argument is a List of things and the argument resolver doesn't see the "things"; with `@Payload(required = false) Foo` we can detect the KafkaNull in the argument resolver.

If you [open a GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues) referencing this question, we can take a look at resolving it for batch listeners too.

Comment: As a work-around, `List<ConsumerRecord<?, String>>` should work (if you are using a `StringDeserializer`).

Comment: Gary Russell thanks you for answer. Issue is there: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/974